# Expresso: international orders not able to complete

Tags: expresso-store

A client, whose website I did not develop, is having intermittent problems with international orders.  Customers are not able to progress from the initial cart/address screen to any other page.
I think a fix for this client shouldn't be too hard, but since I'm not an EE developer, I don't know how to do it. The client wants shipping charges to be automatically generated for U.S. orders only. All international orders will require direct follow-up. So, how do I set it up so that shipping cost information is suppressed for all international orders and visible only for U.S. orders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you just use the built in shipping option and set a price only for United States and set all other countries to 0 it should work pretty automatic. Then detect if the price is 0 with an if statement in the cart/checkout and show the message you want. Then if someone chooses US you will get the price added.

This could vary depending on your shipping setup though.